# Tips for approaching a closed set problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let C be a closed set of real numbers and let a be a real number. For any $\epsilon>0$, let $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)\cap C \neq \emptyset.$ Prove that $a \in C$.

I'm attempting to show that there must be a sequence in C that converges to a, thus forcing a to be in C by the properties of closed sets, but I'm having trouble with the fact that a term in $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$ is not necessarily in $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)\cap C.$ Am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For an $\epsilon >0$ $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)\cap C \neq \Phi$

Consider $\epsilon_n=\frac{\epsilon}{n}$.

Now for each $\epsilon_n$ $\exists a_n \in (a-\epsilon_n,a+\epsilon_n)\cap C$.

The sequence$\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$ as $\epsilon_n$ converges to $0$.

Therefore you have your sequence $a_n$ in $C$ which converges to $a$, which will prove that $C$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

First approach: For each positive integer $n$ let $x_n$ be an element of the open interval $(a-1/n,a+1/n).$ Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=a.$

Second approach: Prove the contrapositive. Note that since $C$ is closed, its complement is open and every point of an open set is an interior point of the set.

Comment: The O.P is trying to prove it by constructing a sequence in $C$ which converges to $a$.

Comment: @Babai Sorry, I have edited my answer.

Comment: It is perfect now.